# Multilingual site - how to do continuous translation?

Tags: localization, craft4

We are making a site multilingual. It will have multiple geographical target areas as well as multiple languages per location.

How can we cause ourselves the least amount of pain when constructing the "continuous translation process"? I see there is a [Translation](https://plugins.craftcms.com/translations?craft4) plugin from Acclaro, which I assume does this by leveraging Acclaro's translation product. It is quite pricey though, and I wonder if there are other alternatives (even analog ones like using a spreadsheet to track translation).

Comment: This is quite a broad question – what exactly is the problem you're trying to solve? Craft has full multi-language support, so in theory it has all you need to manage a multilingual website. Is there a particular feature you're missing in the core?